# Как увеличивать размер объекта? unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно через код увеличивать anchors у Rect Transform на заданное число.
Например: был max Y = 1, стал 1.1

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMax = new Vector2(x, y);
GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMin = new Vector2(x, y);
```

Отмечу, что `anchors` не увеличивает и не уменьшает размер объекта (как Вы хотите в заголовке топика), а указывает точки привязки объекта к родительскому.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы при изменении размеров anchorMin у объекта, дочерний объект сохранял свои позиции, относительно экрана.

Comment: @DmitryDAN, по идее, если Вы в рантайме меняете `anchor` (якорь), родительский и дочерний объекты должны остаться на месте. Якоря нужны для позиционирования объектов (например интерфейса) относительно экрана для разных разрешений дисплеев и, как правило, задаются только в инспекторе редактора.

Comment: Вот:http://recordit.co/tdYTiXhWFi
Меняю размер "Content" на 1, после чего "GameObject" расплющивает.

Comment: @DmitryDAN, в том и дело, что расплющивает. Заметьте, до запуска проекта, `Content` у Вас имеет правильную привязку к углам. После манипуляций верхние якоря "цепляются" за пустоту, что крайне не хорошо и в дальнейшем может потрепать нервы. Если Вам надо изменять размеры объекта в режиме привязки, используйте `GetComponent<RectTransform>().offsetMin/Max` либо уж изменяйте `transform.localscale` объекта.